# Django model inheritance and type check

Tags: python, django

```
class Machine(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField( max_length=120)
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Car(Machine):
    speed = models.IntegerField()

class Computer(Machine)
    ram = models.IntegerField()
```

My question is, how can I understand what type is the Machine model. For instamce I know the incoming query is a children of the Machine model but I also want to know it is a Car submodel.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly. ***If*** you are trying to find out the type of a given instance you can use the built-in `type` function.

```
an_object = Car(name = "foo", speed = 80)
an_object.save()
type(an_object) # <class 'project.app.models.Car'>
```

Or if you wish to check if `an_object` is an instance of `Car` you can use `isinstance`.

```
isinstance(an_object, Car) # True
```

Answer (score 12):

isinstance would work only if you fetched the object calling the Car class.
if you do Machine.objects.all() and later want to know if is a car, what you can do is use hasattr. like:

```
o = Machine.objects.all()[0]
print(hasattr(o, 'car'))
```