# Compare Django child classes of abstract model in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-orm

I have two classes as childs of abstract class (example below).
How to check if queryset model is one or other of these classes?

```
class Parent(models.Model)
    field_a =  models.CharField(primary_key = True, max_length = 24)
    field_b =  models.CharField(primary_key = True, max_length = 24)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class A(Parent)
    pass

class B(Parent)
    pass
```

I have tired something like this but it's not working:

```
if type(queryset.model) == type(A):
    do something...
elif type(queryset.model) == type(B):
    do something else...
```

because when I check the type(queryset.model) it's returns type(Parent), 
even the queryset.model is the A or B class.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django model inheritance and type check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438003/django-model-inheritance-and-type-check)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using \`issubclass()\` with Django models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914787/using-issubclass-with-django-models)

Comment: No, none of them answers my question. I posted my solution down below.

Answer (score 0):

To be more precise *issubclass* is not working. 
*isinstance* method is not working too because the object which I check is not instance.

my problem is for example when i have queryset of one of child models, and when I don't know exactly which one how do I check this?

for example:

```
queryset = A.objects.all()
# or 
queryset = B.objects.all()
```

if I don't ktow the queryset (dynamic method) this check like this it returns false for boths conditions:

```
if type(queryset.model) == type(A):
    do something...
elif type(queryset.model) == type(B):
    do something else...
```

because true is:

`type(queryset.model) == type(Parent)`

my solution is to use __name__ but I don't know if there is a better way?

```
if queryset.model.__name__ == A.__name__:
    do something...
elif queryset.model.__name__ == B.__name__:
    do something else...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should compare queryset.model directly with the class.

Something like this should work:

```
if queryset.model == A:
    # do your stuff
```